# How can I split an array key values so it iterates with another foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I'm not sure if I'm using the right expressions here to describe what I need. However, what I mean is that I have two different arrays, and I need to split a specific array key values within another array's foreach loop.

Take the following as a real example.

```
// This comes from a repeatable group of fields 

$food_prices = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_prefix_food_price_group', true );

// I get the repeatable group fields' values with the following foreach loop:

foreach ((array) $food_prices as $key => $value) {


    if (!(isset($value['price_legend']))) { 
        // do nothing
    } else {
        $price_label =  esc_html($value['price_label']);
    }

    if (!(isset($value['price']))) { 
        // do nothing
    } else {
        $sale_price =  esc_html($value['price']);
    }

    echo '<div><span>Label: </span>'. $price_label .'</div>';
    echo '<div><span>Price: </span>'. $sale_price .'</div>';

}
```

For whatever values I set for the custom fields above while editing the post, the foreach loop above would result in something like this:

**Price:** **25,90**

**Price:** **32,90**

**Price:** **39,90**

So far, the above gives me all the repeated `price` field values, but it also implies I'd get the values that were manually set on a per post basis. Although it is the expected behavior, I thought that creating a global pricing options would allow for an easy maintenance in case prices change.

...

For that to happen I created a function that will later grab the "global" pricing options from the theme's option, but for now I've kind of manually created an array with values that would replace the post's repeatable custom fields if set, so here's the function:

```
function get_global_food_menu_prices() {

    //$small_pizza = get_option( $post_id, 'small_size_price' );
    $small_pizza[0] = '25,90';
    $medium_pizza[1] = '32,90';
    $large_pizza[2] = '39,90';

    $food_menu_prices = ['small_pizza'=>$small_pizza, 'medium_pizza'=>$medium_pizza, 'large_pizza'=>$large_pizza];

      return $food_menu_prices;

    //var_dump($food_menu_prices);

}
```

The above `var_dump($food_menu_prices);` results in the following:

```
array (size=3)
    'samll_pizza' => 
        array (size=1)
            0 => string '25,90' (length=5)
    'medium_pizza' => 
        array (size=1)
            1 => string '32,90' (length=5)
    'large_pizza' => 
        array (size=1)
            2 => string '39,90' (length=5)
```

Now, how could I get the key values of the array `$food_menu_prices` to be split on each iteration of the first foreach loop?

What I mean with "split" is that for each time the first foreach would print a repeated `price` key value from its array of values, then I'd like it to print a key value from the `$food_menu_prices` array instead.

I've tried something like the following below, but it returns all key values from the `get_global_food_menu_prices()` function.

```
foreach ((array) $food_prices as $key => $value) {


    if (!(isset($value['price_legend']))) { 
        // do nothing
    } else {
        $price_label =  esc_html($value['price_label']);
    }

    if (!(isset($value['price']))) { 
        // do nothing
    } else {
        $sale_price =  esc_html($value['price']);
    }

    echo '<div><span>Label: </span>'. $price_label .'</div>';

    if function_exists('get_global_food_menu_prices') { 
        echo get_global_food_menu_prices();
    } else {
        echo '<div><span>Price: </span>'. $sale_price .'</div>';
    }

}
```

Obviously, it returns this:

**Price:** **25,90 32,90 39,90** when I'd like each key value to be echoed separately within the foreach loop above.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure what you mean by "split".

I think

```
$small_pizza = '25,90';
$medium_pizza = '32,90';
$large_pizza = '39,90';

$food_menu_prices = ['small_pizza'=>$small_pizza, 'medium_pizza'=>$medium_pizza, 'large_pizza'=>$large_pizza];
```

will set the values you want in `$food_menu_prices` hash. I assume you want to access this in the first `foreach` where you want to lookup the global price of pizza based on size. This should work.

Comment: thanks for the input. Well, perhaps I'm not being clear enough on trying to explain what I'd like to achieve, but yes, I'd like to get the key values from `$food_menu_prices` to be echoed separately in the first foreach loop.

Comment: Then what I gave you should work. You can now use

`$food_menu_prices['small_pizza']` in the first foreach loop to get the value `'29,90'` and `$food_menu_prices['medium_pizza']` for '32,90' and so on.